# Melt/Stack/Reshape multi header dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-melt

I've scraped from data from excel that has more than one header row of data, with some nans in one row:

df = pd.read_excel(file, header=None)

```
0  nan  nan   jan20  jan20  feb20  feb20
1  ID   Name   GrpA   GrpB   GrpA   GrpB
2  1    One     1       2      3     4
3  2    Two     5       6      7     8
```

Each ID/Name pair has 4 pieces of data it needs to be associated with.  The goal for the data is to look like:

```
ID Name
1   One jan20 grpA 1
1   One jan20 grpB 2
1   One feb20 grpA 3
1   One feb20 grpB 4
2   Two jan20 grpA 5
2   Two jan20 grpB 6 
2   Two feb20 grpA 7
2   Two feb20 grpB 8
```

Note when this is scraped, I don't indicate the header rows upon import, as there is some cleaning of the data to do.  I've tried lots of various combinations of pd.melt, pd.stack, pd.unstack, but not getting there.  I've tried making the first two rows both header rows, but then I have problems with the keys.

It seems like .melt might be the right answer because you can choose a col_level and could name the resulting columns, but when I try that route I can't access the dates (first row) it seems

df.melt(col_level=1, id_vars=['ID'])

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Are the nans actual nans or just strings that look like nans?

Comment: Actual NaNs, they are blank spaces read into the df by pd.read_excel

Comment: Is the `nan nan jan20 ...` the first row? Or the columns?

Comment: First row has no headers - i edited the post above

Comment: So row `0` in your sample is the first *row* of `df` (the dataframe, not the spreadsheet)?

Comment: Correct.  First row of the df.  Per Beny's answer below (and my response) I have some data cleaning to do after I load the excel spread sheet, so i can't do: ```pd.read_excel(File, header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the lines of your sample are all *rows* of the dataframe (not spreadsheet), this should work. Here I'm creating a 2-level MultiIndex containing the 2 first rows, then dropping those rows, and doing 2 `melt`s.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1]])
df = df.iloc[2:] # trim off the first 2 rows after we put them in the MultiIndex

tmp = df.melt(id_vars=['ID', 'Name'], col_level=1)
tmp['x'] = df.melt(col_level=0).dropna()[0].to_numpy()
tmp = tmp.rename({1: 'y', 'value': 'z'}, axis=1).set_index(['ID', 'Name'])[['x', 'y', 'z']].sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> tmp
             x     y  z
ID Name                
1  One   jan20  GrpA  1
   One   jan20  GrpB  2
   One   feb20  GrpA  3
   One   feb20  GrpB  4
2  Two   jan20  GrpA  5
   Two   jan20  GrpB  6
   Two   feb20  GrpA  7
   Two   feb20  GrpB  8
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had similar to your first three lines of code, but then couldn't get the dates which you are getting in your 4th line.  What is the reason for dropping NA and converting this to Numpy?  I tried the code without that part and it didn't seem to work.  It seems almost like a merge but there is no key to merge on.

Comment: `dropna` because there were some nans in the first row; `to_numpy()` to get rid of the index so I could simply insert the values in the dataframe. Before I added `to_numpy()`, there were index issues.

Answer (score 1):

Let us load the file correctly

```
df = pd.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx', 
                   header=[0,1], 
                   index_col=[0,1])
```

Then you can just do `stack` twice

```
out = df.stack().stack()
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is a bunch of data cleaning to be done in the file (merged cells etc) so I can't load the headers while reading the excel file...

Answer (score 1):

A crude way can be to manually reshape:

```
(df
 .set_index([0,1]).T
 .set_index([(float('nan'), float('nan')), ('ID', 'Name')])
 .rename_axis(index=[None,None], columns=[None,None])
 .stack()
 .stack()
)
```

Output:

```
jan20  GrpA  One  1    1
             Two  2    5
       GrpB  One  1    2
             Two  2    6
feb20  GrpA  One  1    3
             Two  2    7
       GrpB  One  1    4
             Two  2    8
dtype: object
```